# why set string = '' integer = 0 in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am  really new to python and never coded before.
learning python by myself is fun and I do have a lot of questions that I have no one to ask. One of them is

why do I need to set `string = ''` or `integer = 0` in function before doing something.

ex:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCEfG.png)

Comment: Please directly include your code in the question, rather than linking to a screenshot. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: Because if you didn't, when you tried to use them in `guess != rannum` they don't have values so Python can't perform the comparison

Comment: @dantechguy Please don't post answers in the comments

Comment: There are no variables named `string` or `integer` in the [screenshot you posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCEfG.png). You're referring to `guess = 0`, right?

Comment: sorry for adding the picture a was new and never use  stackoverflow before thank you very much for the answer and really sorry for using a picture.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the `while` loop compares the value of the user's `guess` with the value of the random number `rannum` picked by your program. As the user hasn't yet been asked for a number, the variable `guess` would not exist yet if we hadn't defined it before, and the program would crash with a `NameError: name 'guess' is not defined` when it tries to enter the loop.

Comment: It's worth adding that 0 is outside the range of possible guesses, which makes it a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Comment: thank you , from my understanding adding string = '' or integer = 0 is simply to tell python that the variable is a string or an integer, am i right.

Comment: @user15673901 Not really. In your example, Python needs a value to compare it to the random number, and you're telling it that it can find this value in the variable guess. If that variable doesn't exist, it can't find the value it needs, and will crash. Python is a dynamically-typed language, and as such, doesn't really care about the type of a variable.